# neo4j data formatting slows query

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

I have a fairly long involved Cypher query that I need to run on a Neo4j database of approximately 1 million nodes. The actual query is pretty simple, but I have added some logic to format the data into something that can be quickly used once we return it back to our API. Additionally, the integrity of the data is not perfect, and we have some duplicate entries, so I have added logic to deal with this as well. However, the query takes around a minute to execute currently, which is definitely too slow. **I have noticed that just returning the nodes and not doing any data formatting speeds the query up to around a second, so I am fairly confident the issue occurs when formatting the data and ensuring uniqueness.** I thought that using `DISTINCT` might really slow things down, but after removing it I don't see any noticeable speed up. Am I making any glaring errors here that would really hurt performance?

#### Original Query

```
OPTIONAL MATCH
(p:Person)-[:WROTE]->(b:Edition)<-[:PUBLISHED]-(pub:Publisher)-[:PUBLISHES_IN]->(plc:Place)
WHERE
b.title =~ { regex }
WITH
{
    title: b.title,
    isbn: b.isbn,
    date: toString( b.date ),
    id: toString( id(b) ),
    authors: collect(
    DISTINCT {
        name: p.name,
        id: toString( id(p) ) 
    }), 
    publishers: collect(
    DISTINCT {
        name: pub.name,
        id: toString( id(pub) )
    }),
    places: collect(
    DISTINCT {
        name: plc.name,
        id: toString( id(plc) )
    }),
    relationships: {
        wrote: collect(
        DISTINCT [
            toString( id(p) ),
            toString( id(b) )
        ]),
        published: collect(
        DISTINCT [
            toString( id(pub) ),
            toString( id(b) )
        ]),
        publishes_in: collect(
        DISTINCT [
            toString( id(pub) ),
            toString( id(plc) )
        ])
    }
} as tmp
WITH
collect( DISTINCT tmp ) as records

UNWIND records as r
RETURN DISTINCT
    CASE
        WHEN (r.title IS NULL OR r.authors IS NULL OR r.publishers IS NULL) THEN NULL
        ELSE r
    END AS res
LIMIT { limit }
```

#### Query Without Formatting Logic

```
OPTIONAL MATCH
(p:Person)-[:WROTE]->(b:Edition)<-[:PUBLISHED]-(pub:Publisher)-[:PUBLISHES_IN]->(plc:Place)
WHERE
b.title =~ { regex }
RETURN p, b, pub, plc
LIMIT { limit }
```

It is possible for me to just return the nodes and relationships and then do further data processing with javascript, but neo4j returns data from the driver in a somewhat messy format and I'd rather just do it in Cypher if possible. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are using a `regex`, and it can't use indexes. If it's possible, I recommend you to use `CONTAINS`, `STARTS WITH` or `ENDS WITH`.

In your query, you are doing a lot of `COLLECT` and `DISTINCT`. Those element consume some time and a lot of RAM.

At the end of your query you are doing a `COLLECT` and then an `UNWIND` on it. This part can be simplify like that :

```
WITH collect( DISTINCT tmp ) as records
UNWIND records as r
RETURN DISTINCT
    CASE
        WHEN (r.title IS NULL OR r.authors IS NULL OR r.publishers IS NULL) THEN NULL
        ELSE r
    END AS res
```

becomes :

```
WITH DISTINCT tmp as r
RETURN DISTINCT
    CASE
        WHEN (r.title IS NULL OR r.authors IS NULL OR r.publishers IS NULL) THEN NULL
        ELSE r
    END AS res
```

Moreover, in the case you seem to filter the result. You should put those conditions directly in the `MATCH` clause.

So finally your query should be :

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (p:Person)-[:WROTE]->(b:Edition)<-[:PUBLISHED]-(pub:Publisher)-[:PUBLISHES_IN]->(plc:Place)
WHERE
  b.title =~ { regex } AND 
  NOT b.title IS NULL AND
  size((b)<-[:WROTE]-()) > 0 AND
  size((b)<-[:PUBLISHED]-()) > 0

WITH
{
    title: b.title,
    isbn: b.isbn,
    date: toString( b.date ),
    id: toString( id(b) ),
    authors: collect(
    DISTINCT {
        name: p.name,
        id: toString( id(p) ) 
    }), 
    publishers: collect(
    DISTINCT {
        name: pub.name,
        id: toString( id(pub) )
    }),
    places: collect(
    DISTINCT {
        name: plc.name,
        id: toString( id(plc) )
    }),
    relationships: {
        wrote: collect(
        DISTINCT [
            toString( id(p) ),
            toString( id(b) )
        ]),
        published: collect(
        DISTINCT [
            toString( id(pub) ),
            toString( id(b) )
        ]),
        publishes_in: collect(
        DISTINCT [
            toString( id(pub) ),
            toString( id(plc) )
        ])
    }
} as record
RETURN DISTINCT record
LIMIT {limit}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! These alterations brought my query time down to the order of a couple seconds. Also I figured that using a `regex` would lead to decreased performance, but I really would like to be able to do case insensitive matching, which it doesn't seem is possible with `CONTAINS`. Are you aware of another way to do case insensitive matching that is more efficient?